# Mac Terminal Git not working

Tags: git, macos

After upgrading to macOS Sierra, I tried to run git from Terminal but it is giving this error as :

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun.

Any suggestions, how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this after googling the issue,

Open Terminal, and run the following:

```
xcode-select --reset
```

If it is not allowing reset the run following and install the same.

```
xcode-select --install
```